Hide product categories if empty by leaving them positioned in the same place in the menu
Hello, I integrated this same code to hide a category when it is empty and it works well. But I would like it to be positioned in the same place when a product is added again. Today, it is positioned at the very bottom of the menu. Do you have a solution to hide this category without it moving? Thanks for your help ?
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'nav_remove_empty_category_menu_item', 10, 3 );

function nav_remove_empty_category_menu_item ( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $nopost = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE count = 0" );
    foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
        if ( ( 'taxonomy' == $item->type ) && ( in_array( $item->object_id, $nopost ) ) ) {
            unset( $items[$key] );
        }
    }
    return $items;
}


I can see nothing in that code is moving the menu item, are you sure the reason it's showing at the end is because it's at the end of the menu? How is it being inserted? Note this is an X Y problem, it might be easier to ask how to hide empty categories in a menu than it would be to ask how to fix this code

in fact, this code allows me to hide an empty category. The problem is that when this same category fills up again, it is automatically placed at the bottom of the menu in "Appearance > Menu. I would like it not to move in position. Can you help me?

I understand that, but you did not answer any of my questions, are you manually adding the categories to the nav menu? Is code or a plugin adding the categories? The filter you're trying to fix is not hiding items, it's deleting them. Where did you get the code from?

actually, I manually add the categories in Appearance > Menu.
The code was found on the net and added to function.php of my child theme.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Good morning,
I summarize in detail; I have a menu and I manually organize the order of categories. I placed a code in “function.php” of my child theme this code below
us so that when a category is empty of products, it is hidden. But my concern today is that when this same category fills up again, it is placed at the very bottom of the menu, whereas I would like it to keep its initial position. I hope to be clearer this time. THANKS
https://www.levindevantoi.com/

https://www.levindevantsoi.com/

#Resolu#
Voilà le code que je cherchais :
/*

Hide empty categories from nav menus
*/
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'gowp_nav_remove_empty_terms', 10, 3 );
function gowp_nav_remove_empty_terms ( $items, $menu, $args ) {
global $wpdb;
$empty = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE count = 0" );
foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
if ( ( 'taxonomy' == $item->type ) && ( in_array( $item->object_id, $empty ) ) ) {
unset( $items[$key] );
}
}
return $items;
}


I think with your question to hide the empty product categories in menu, we can add extra class for this menu item then adding CSS to hide these specific items.

This code will add extra class hidden to empty product categories

add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', function($classes, $menu_item, $args, $depth){
    if('taxonomy' == $menu_item->type){
        $term_id = $menu_item->object_id;
        $term    = get_term($term_id, $menu_item->object);
        if(!is_wp_error($term)){
            if($term->count <= 0){
                $classes [] = 'hidden';
            }
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}, 10, 4);


Then adding new CSS to hide these items

    .hidden {display:none;}

